# Is it possible to get all the clicks associated with any video/photo of any user that I wish, using INSTAGRAM API?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, web-crawler, instagram

Is it possible to get all the clicks (timestamped activities including comments, likes and shares) associated with any video/picture of any user that i wish, using Instagram API? i am not gonna limit myself to only my uploaded stuff! Basically I would like to creates a stream of clicks on popular photos or videos on Instagram. Also, I  would like to have timestamps of follow-up activities on a particular video/picture rather counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can get timestamps of comments from any image/video. However, you can't get timestamps when a user liked a picture. There isn't an endpoint where you can get info if someone shared the photo/video.

If you would like to create a stream of follow-up activities on a particular picture, you would have a script that calls out via Instagram's API every minute, save the JSON data, and then do a comparison to see if anything new happened.

If you sign up with Instagram's API, you can see what other data you can access:
http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/